# speeding up a non-equal join

Tags: r, data.table

Inputs

```
> specialty.dt
   specialty        p1        p2
1:      ZKWM 0.0000000 0.7377049
2:      MZAY 0.7377049 1.0000000

> provider.dt
   provSysId       prob
1:        23 0.94225972
2:        16 0.39277028
3:         8 0.07162044
4:        25 0.42598790
5:         7 0.90370561
6:        12 0.71343887
```

Output

```
> prov_spec.dt
   provSysId       prob specialty        p1        p2
1:        23 0.94225972      MZAY 0.7377049 1.0000000
2:        16 0.39277028      ZKWM 0.0000000 0.7377049
3:         8 0.07162044      ZKWM 0.0000000 0.7377049
4:        25 0.42598790      ZKWM 0.0000000 0.7377049
5:         7 0.90370561      MZAY 0.7377049 1.0000000
6:        12 0.71343887      ZKWM 0.0000000 0.7377049
```

Code to create above tables is shown below.  For `num.provider=5` and `num.specialty=10000`, it takes almost 30s to create the output.  I was wondering if there was a faster way to get the same result (without first doing a cartesian product because that would require a lot of memory).

```
require(data.table)

num.specialty <- 50
num.provider <- 10000

specialty.dt <- data.table(specialty=replicate(num.specialty, paste(sample(LETTERS, 4, replace=TRUE), collapse="")))[,
    cnt:=sample(1:50, .N, replace=T)][, prob:=cnt/sum(cnt)][, p2:=cumsum(prob)][, p1:=shift(p2,,0)][, 
    c("specialty","p1","p2"), with=FALSE]

provider.dt <- data.table(provSysId=sample(seq(num.provider+1,num.provider*5), num.provider, replace=FALSE))[, prob:=runif(.N)]

system.time({
prov_spec.dt <- rbindlist(lapply(1:num.provider, function(n) {r <- provider.dt[n]; cbind(r,specialty.dt[p1 <= r[,prob] & r[,prob] < p2]) }))
})
```

Comment: it's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, but I think it's along the lines of `specialty.dt[ provider.dt, on = .(p1 <= prob, p2 > prob)]` (using `data.table v1.9.7`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `rbindlist(lapply(...))` can be replaced with a *non-equi* join using [version 1.9.7 of data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md)

```
specialty.dt[ provider.dt, on = .(p1 <= prob, p2 > prob)]
```

This joins `specialty.dt` onto `provider.dt` directly, using the condition that `p1 <= prob`, and `prob < p2`.

---

References

[Here's a list of similar questions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Non-equi-joins-Q-on-SO)

[And here's a talk by Arun](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conference/useR2016/Efficient-in-memory-non-equi-joins-using-datatable)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link to Arun's talk.